# Reorder XML records based on one or more elements or attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, element

I have an input file in XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <m2:M006 xmlns:m2="http://www.mym2.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mym2.com http://www.mym2.com/schemas/M2RequestSchema.xsd"><M001><tkn /><m2xmlReleaseNo>020</m2xmlReleaseNo><mvmtHdr mvmtTp="CRT">
       <cmt>Reduction of nominal</cmt>
     </mvmtHdr><mvmtSrc>
       <ctlr>SAR</ctlr>
       <ctlrMvmtRef>464082138</ctlrMvmtRef>
       <srcRecType>Cash Transaction</srcRecType>
       <srcTransType>Reduction of Nominal</srcTransType>
     </mvmtSrc><extSys>
       <extSysID>SAR</extSysID>
       <extSysRef>464082138</extSysRef>
     </extSys><hldCpt1 amtScheme="m2">
       <hldId>
         <ctlrOwnr>6.00595-6</ctlrOwnr>
         <ctlrAcct>6005956.6000</ctlrAcct>
         <ownrRefCcy>CHF</ownrRefCcy>
         <ccy>CHF</ccy>
         <asst>CH0013841017</asst>
         <asstIDs>
           <asstRef refType="ISIN">CH0013841017</asstRef>
           <asstRef refType="Valor">1384101</asstRef>
           <asstRef refType="SARA">000000426547</asstRef>
         </asstIDs>
         <asstDetail>
           <isin>CH0013841017</isin>
           <type>Shares</type>
           <cntry>CH/Switzerland</cntry>
           <desc>Lonza Group AG Nam.</desc>
           <issueCcy>CHF</issueCcy>
           <latestPrc ccy="CHF">126.50</latestPrc>
           <latestPrcDate>2015-04-14</latestPrcDate>
         </asstDetail>
       </hldId>
       <effDt>2015-04-14</effDt>
       <settleDt>2015-04-14</settleDt>
       <qty>5000</qty>
       <prc ccy="CHF">2.5</prc>
       <grTrdAmt ccy="CHF">-12500</grTrdAmt>
       <grAmt ccy="CHF">-12500</grAmt>
       <netAmt ccy="CHF">-12500</netAmt>
     </hldCpt1><hldCpt2 amtScheme="m2">
       <hldId>
         <ctlrOwnr>6.00595-6</ctlrOwnr>
         <ctlrAcct>6005956.4000/CHF/KK</ctlrAcct>
         <ccy>CHF</ccy>
         <asst>CHF</asst>
         <asstIDs>
           <asstRef refType="CURRENCY">CHF</asstRef>
         </asstIDs>
       </hldId>
       <effDt>2015-04-14</effDt>
       <grAmt ccy="CHF">12500</grAmt>
       <netAmt ccy="CHF">12500</netAmt>
     </hldCpt2></M001><M001><tkn /><m2xmlReleaseNo>020</m2xmlReleaseNo><mvmtHdr mvmtTp="CCL">
       <cmt>Variation Margin</cmt>
     </mvmtHdr><mvmtSrc>
       <ctlr>SAR</ctlr>
       <ctlrMvmtRef>464068243</ctlrMvmtRef>
       <srcRecType>Cash Transaction</srcRecType>
       <srcTransType>Variation Margin</srcTransType>
     </mvmtSrc><extSys>
       <extSysID>SAR</extSysID>
       <extSysRef>464068243</extSysRef>
     </extSys><hldCpt1 amtScheme="m2">
       <hldId>
         <ctlrOwnr>6.00767-3</ctlrOwnr>
         <ctlrAcct>6007673.6000</ctlrAcct>
         <ownrRefCcy>EUR</ownrRefCcy>
         <ccy>EUR</ccy>
         <asst>73896793</asst>
         <asstIDs>
           <asstRef refType="Valor">73896793</asstRef>
           <asstRef refType="SARA">000125009930</asstRef>
         </asstIDs>
         <asstDetail>
           <type>Future</type>
           <cntry>DE/Germany</cntry>
           <desc>FGBL - BUND FUTURES Jun15 EUX</desc>
           <issueCcy>EUR</issueCcy>
           <latestPrc ccy="EUR">159.54</latestPrc>
           <latestPrcDate>2015-04-14</latestPrcDate>
           <asstDerivDetails>
             <contractSize>100000</contractSize>
             <expDate>2015-06-08</expDate>
             <underlyingAsstIDs>
               <asstRef refType="Valor">0000004209</asstRef>
             </underlyingAsstIDs>
           </asstDerivDetails>
         </asstDetail>
       </hldId>
       <effDt>2015-04-14</effDt>
       <settleDt>2015-04-14</settleDt>
       <qty>-10</qty>
       <prc ccy="EUR">989898</prc>
       <grTrdAmt ccy="EUR">100</grTrdAmt>
       <grAmt ccy="EUR">100</grAmt>
       <netAmt ccy="EUR">100</netAmt>
     </hldCpt1><hldCpt2 amtScheme="m2">
       <hldId>
         <ctlrOwnr>6.00767-3</ctlrOwnr>
         <ctlrAcct>6007673.4004/EUR/KK 'Variation Margin'</ctlrAcct>
         <ccy>EUR</ccy>
         <asst>EUR</asst>
         <asstIDs>
           <asstRef refType="CURRENCY">EUR</asstRef>
         </asstIDs>
       </hldId>
       <effDt>2015-04-14</effDt>
       <grAmt ccy="EUR">-100</grAmt>
       <netAmt ccy="EUR">-100</netAmt>
     </hldCpt2></M001><M001><tkn /><m2xmlReleaseNo>020</m2xmlReleaseNo><mvmtHdr mvmtTp="AOU">
       <cmt>Variation Margin</cmt>
     </mvmtHdr><mvmtSrc>
       <ctlr>SAR</ctlr>
       <ctlrMvmtRef>464068485</ctlrMvmtRef>
       <srcRecType>Cash Transaction</srcRecType>
       <srcTransType>Variation Margin</srcTransType>
     </mvmtSrc><extSys>
       <extSysID>SAR</extSysID>
       <extSysRef>464068485</extSysRef>
     </extSys><hldCpt1 amtScheme="m2">
       <hldId>
         <ctlrOwnr>6.01279-4</ctlrOwnr>
         <ctlrAcct>6012794.6000</ctlrAcct>
         <ownrRefCcy>EUR</ownrRefCcy>
         <ccy>CHF</ccy>
         <asst>74040383</asst>
         <asstIDs>
           <asstRef refType="Valor">74040383</asstRef>
           <asstRef refType="SARA">000125132191</asstRef>
         </asstIDs>
         <asstDetail>
           <type>Future</type>
           <cntry>CH/Switzerland</cntry>
           <desc>FSMI FUTURES Jun15 EUX</desc>
           <issueCcy>CHF</issueCcy>
           <latestPrc ccy="CHF">9288.00</latestPrc>
           <latestPrcDate>2015-04-14</latestPrcDate>
           <asstDerivDetails>
             <contractSize>10</contractSize>
             <expDate>2015-06-19</expDate>
             <underlyingAsstIDs>
               <asstRef refType="Valor">0000004208</asstRef>
             </underlyingAsstIDs>
           </asstDerivDetails>
         </asstDetail>
       </hldId>
       <effDt>2015-04-14</effDt>
       <settleDt>2015-04-14</settleDt>
       <qty>-14</qty>
       <prc ccy="CHF">989898</prc>
       <grTrdAmt ccy="CHF">-6440</grTrdAmt>
       <grAmt ccy="CHF">-6440</grAmt>
       <netAmt ccy="CHF">-6440</netAmt>
     </hldCpt1><hldCpt2 amtScheme="m2">
       <hldId>
         <ctlrOwnr>6.01279-4</ctlrOwnr>
         <ctlrAcct>6012794.4019/CHF/KK 'Variation Margin'</ctlrAcct>
         <ccy>CHF</ccy>
         <asst>CHF</asst>
         <asstIDs>
           <asstRef refType="CURRENCY">CHF</asstRef>
         </asstIDs>
       </hldId>
       <effDt>2015-04-14</effDt>
       <grAmt ccy="CHF">6440</grAmt>
       <netAmt ccy="CHF">6440</netAmt>
     </hldCpt2></M001></m2:M006>
```

Before I process the file I have to reorder the M001 Records.  The order should be:

1. `<ctlrMvmtRef>XXXXXXXXX</ctlrMvmtRef>`
2. `mvmtTp="XXX"`

The data itself should stay untouched.   Just the M001 Records should be reordered.

i tried with this xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
         <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="M006">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="mvmtTp" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but this didn't work

this one works

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::comment())][not(self::*)]|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="mvmtSrc/ctlrMvmtRef"/>
        <xsl:sort select="mvmtHdr/@mvmtTp"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

one more point, if i don't want to sort mvmtTp in strict alphabetical order e.g.
instead of
AIN
AOU
DEP
like this
AOU
AIN
DEP

that means AOU always before AIN

Comment: What is your question?   "How do I do this" will be too broad, btw.

Comment: i want to do this with xslt and i'm new to xslt

Comment: Then you really should state XSLT somewhere in your question and use the XSLT tag too.  Please also format your XML as code; it's unreadable the way you have it.  You should also prune your XML down to a minimal size, and show what that minimal XML should look like in the output.  Finally, you ideally should write some XSLT yourself to show what you've tried.  Thank you.

Comment: I've shown you how to format the code, and I've fixed your capitalization/grammar mistakes.  Please see the additional suggestions I made in the above comment.  If you put effort into formulating your question well, you can get great help here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
       const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument input = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var x = input.Root.Elements("M001").AsEnumerable()
               .OrderBy(y => y.Element("mvmtSrc").Element("ctlrMvmtRef").Value).ToList();

            XDocument doc2 = new XDocument(new XElement("M006", x));


        }
```

Comment: The question is asking for XSLT.

Comment: Original posting didn't have XSLT.